# Understanding all sub-$\sigma$-algebras of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose I have a set $\Omega$, and I partition $\Omega$ into $4$ sets $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, A_{4}$.

Clearly, the $A_{i}$'s are pairwise disjoint and their union equals $\Omega$.  Now, it's also clear to me that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by these four sets is just the set of all possible unions of these, as well as $\emptyset$.

I'm wondering if the only sub-$\sigma$-algebras of this $\sigma$-algebra are only the $\sigma$-algebra $\{\Omega, \emptyset \}$ and $\sigma(A_{1})$, $\sigma(A_{2})$, $\sigma(A_{3})$, and $\sigma(A_{4})$.  For each $i$, $\sigma(A_{i}) = \{ \emptyset, \Omega, A_{i}, A_{i}^{c} \}$, which shows that the intersection of any of four the $\sigma$-algebras I listed above (which has to be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra itself) is just $\{\Omega, \emptyset \}$.

Is it true that these are the only sub-$\sigma$-algebras?  What if we can partition $\Omega$ into countably many sets? Does the same statement hold?

Comment: I think it's not hard to show that any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on a finite or countable set $\Omega$ consists of a partition of $\Omega$ into finitely or countably many sets, together with all unions of those sets.  (Consider the atoms of $\mathcal{F}$.)  It follows that any sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ is similarly generated by a coarsening of this partition.  Incidentally, this explains why "interesting" probability theory can only be done on uncountable probability spaces.

Comment: @NateEldredge My question didn't specify that $\Omega$ is countable.  So you think it's only true if $\Omega$ is countable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following are also sub-$\sigma$-algebras:

$$\sigma(A_1\cup A_2),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_3),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_4).$$

More generally, let $\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ be a partition of $\Omega$ and let $S=\hat{\sigma}(A_2,A_3,\ldots,A_n)$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega\setminus A_1$.

Then $\sigma(A_1\cup B)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\sigma(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$ for all $B\in S$.

To illustrate, let $n=4$ so that

\begin{eqnarray*}
S &=& \hat{\sigma}(A_2,A_3,A_4) \\
&=& \{\emptyset,\;\;A_2,\;\;A_3,\;\;A_4,\;\;A_2\cup A_3,\;\;A_2\cup A_4,\;\;A_3\cup A_4,\;\;A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4 \}.
\end{eqnarray*}

The $\sigma$-sub-algebras of $\sigma(A_1,\ldots,A_4)$ then are:

$$\qquad\sigma(A_1),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_2),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_3),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_4),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_4),\quad\sigma(A_1\cup A_3\cup A_4),\quad\sigma(\Omega).$$

I think this would apply also to countable partitions.

Comment: Ok, now the question is are each of these sub-$\sigma$-algebras non-trivial?  For example, I had a feeling that $\sigma(A_{1} \cup A_{3}) = \sigma(\Omega)$.  That's what spurred my question in the first place.  Can you show that they are not equal?

Comment: Also, I think the elements of your $S$ are incorrect.  You didn't add $A_{2} \cup A_{3} \cup A_{4}$, and consequently you didn't add the complement of this set, which is $A_{1}$.  Thus, $S$ is actually $\sigma(\Omega)$.

Comment: @user46944 $\sigma(\Omega)$ is just $\{\emptyset,\;\Omega\}$. $\sigma(A_1\cup A_3)=\{\emptyset,\;A_1\cup A_3,\;A_2\cup A_4,\;\Omega\}$.

Comment: @user46944 Note that $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega\setminus A_1$ so $A_1$ cannot appear in it.

Comment: Why would you construct $S$ in that way?  We want $S$ to be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\sigma(\Omega)$, which is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

Comment: I have serious problems with thinking about a $\sigma$-algebra as a subset of $\Omega - A_{1}$.  I've encountered this before in analysis when thinking about whether the integral of a function defined almost everywhere (i.e., with respect the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega - A$ for some null set $A$) equals the integral of an equivalent function defined everywhere (i.e., with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$).  I was never able to show rigorously that these two integrals are the same, so it bothers me that we are using $\sigma(\Omega - A_{1})$ here.

Comment: @user46944 The purpose of $S$ is to be the set of all subsets of $\Omega$ which we can union with $A_1$ to form the sub-$\sigma$-algebras we are seeking. Note the line in my answer "Then $\sigma(A_1\cup B)$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\sigma(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$ for all $B\in S$."

Comment: You have a fair point.  For any set $B$, $\sigma(B) = \{ \emptyset, \Omega, B, B^{c} \}$, which means $\sigma(A_{i} \cup A_{j})$ is a nontrivial sub-$\sigma$-algebra that's not generated by any of the elements in the partition.

Comment: @user46944 Thanks for noticing. Got my caps and cups mixed up. :-)

Comment: Happens to me all the time.  My pants were wet this morning because I tried to drink from my baseball cap.

Comment: @user46944 ha ha ha ... :-)